# Extracting data from series of excel files (MATLAB)

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I'll begin by saying I am really not good in programming especially in extracting data so please bear with me. I think my problem is simple, I just can't figure out how to do it.

My problem is I want to extract part of the data in a series of excel files stored in the same folder. To be specific, let's say I have 10 excel files with 1000 data in each (from A1:A1000). I want to extract the first 100 data (A1:A100) in each excel files and store it in a single variable with a 10x100 size (each row represents each file).

I would really appreciate if any of you can help me. This would make my data processing a lot faster.

EDIT: I have figured out the code but my next problem is to create another loop such that it will reread again the 10 files but this time extract A101:A200 until A901:A1000.

here's the code i've written:

```
for k=1:1:10
 file=['',int2str(k),'.xlsx'];
 data=(xlsread(file,'A1:A100'))';
 z(k,:)=data(1,:);
end
```

I'm not sure how i will edit this part data=(xlsread(file,'A1:A100'))' to do the loop i wanted to do.

Comment: Try looking up the internet in steps: 1. Search for excel file reading, 2. Search for extracting data from excel files, combine them and you are sorted!

Comment: I tried, sorry but i must repeat, but i am not good in programming. I really have a hard time in that "combine them" part that's why i ended up here to ask help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, at least show us what you tried (i.e. code) and where you got stuck. Otherwise, you won't get much help here... This isn't the sort of place where people do your work for you, you have to show some effort first.

Comment: ok i think i made it work, trial and error for the part of array manipulation

for k=1:1:10
file=['',int2str(k),'.xlsx'];
data=(xlsread(file,'A1:A100'))';
z(k,:)=data(1,:);
end

Comment: now i need help in trying to make a loop that will make the next run (reread again the 10 files) but this time it will extract A101:A200. I need to do this until A901:A1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for sec = 1:1:10
    for k=1:1:10
        file=['',int2str(k),'.xlsx'];
        section = ['A', num2str(1+(100*(sec-1)), ':A', mum2str(100*sec)]
        data=(xlsread(file, section))';
        z(k,:)=data(1,:);
    end
    output(sec) = z;
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working. Do you have any idea how to save an image file every loop of the sec? I don't know the syntax to save the filename corresponding to sec.

    for sec = 1:1:10
     for k=1:1:10
        file=['',int2str(k),'.xlsx'];
        section = ['A', num2str(1+(101*(sec-1))), ':A', num2str(101*sec)];
        data=(xlsread(file, section))';
        z(k,:)=data(1,:);
     end
    colormap hot
    pcolor(x,y,z) 
shading interp; 
axis image 

    jpeg=['' ?? ]; 
    saveas(gcf,jpeg);
    end

i have no idea what to write in that jpeg=['' ??]; line

Comment: @Darell glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the check next to it) to mark that it resolved your problem. Also, I encourage you to study nkjt's response, as it is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

> my next problem is to create another loop such that it will reread again the 10 files but this time extract A101:A200 until A901:A1000.

Why?  Why not extract A1:A1000 in one block and then `reshape` or otherwise split up the data?

```
data(k,:)=(xlsread(file,'A1:A1000'))';
```

Then the `A1:A100` data is in `data(k,1:100)`, and so on.  If you do this:

```
data = data(reshape, [10 100 10]);
```

Then `data(:,:,1)` should be your A1:A100 values as in your original loop, and so on until `data(:,:,10)`.

Comment: i don't know if that suits what i want but i need to output an image plot every loop coming from each 100 data of the excel files and so on. So for the 1000 data points, 10 loops = 10 image plots.

Comment: It's more efficient imo to load the data in first, then loop through it to make the plots.

Comment: ok i'll try to use your suggestion and figure it out. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion to loop through the different cells to read. Obviously, you can change how you arrange the collected data in `z`. I have done it as the first index representing the different cells to read (1 for 1:100, 2 for 101:200, etc...), the second index being the file number (as per your original code) and the third index the data (100 data points).

```
% pre-allocate data
z = zeros(10,10,100);

for kk=1:10
   cells_to_read = ['A' num2str(kk*100-99) ':A' num2str(kk*100)];
   for k=1:10
       file=['',int2str(k),'.xlsx'];
       data=(xlsread(file,cells_to_read))';
       z(kk,k,:)=data(1,:);
   end
end
```